# Using HTML 5 tags will make the website responsive one?

Tags: html

I was practicing this website
http://www.lingulo.com/tutorial-content/html5/

While comparing this website with my non-responsive website I was frightened which part of the following header code turns the website mentioned above a responsive one?

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Some Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link href="lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Baumans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>

        <!-- include extern jQuery file but fall back to local file if extern one fails to load !-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js\/vendor\/1.7.2.jquery.min"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="lightbox/js/lightbox.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: "viewport" meta is one such thing, but that alone does not guarantee you that it will make your web page more responsive.

Comment: If you check the style.css of the site. You will find the css is written with media quries. The css written under media section made site responsive

Comment: It's not the head that make a website responsive, it's their CSS and HTML markup. The CSS needs to specify what happens to the page once the viewport is smaller, dimensions change, etc. The `viewport` meta tag helps with it.

Comment: Ok thank you I will work  and practice media queries @ManishShukla

Answer (score 3):

***Yes and No*** and it depends. Lets say for example the `<picture>` tag of HTML5 *is a responsive one but you can't say the same for the other tags.*

Basically the responsiveness is all about fitting your content inside every possible layout of the output device without impacting the design. This is achieved by having the width,height in %'s, Media queries and CSS along with JavaScript etc.

For ease of development *I would recommend you to start with Bootstrap*, which is a light responsive framework used to build responsive websites and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Is the applicable line.

Comment: Here the developer has not used bootstrap  or any libraries . Is it possible to write responsive CSS by our own ?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is a structural markup language - it is simply a set of stylable containers around content. In terms of responsiveness, HTML5 has almost no benefit over HTML4 (there are many other good reasons to use HTML5 though).

The "responsive" part of a website is achieved in how those containers are organised and then styled.

This is usually done in the CSS by using media selectors to specify styles for specific display widths (so, smaller phones or even non-maximised windows have different styles compared to wider screen monitors). Javascript is then used to provide a bit more of an enhancement for behaviour that CSS cannot achieve alone.

So, you want to take a look at the stylesheet located at `css/style.css`

and a good introduction: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can make your website responsive by combining HTML5 and CSS3. Alone, I don't think so. you can refer to below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx